# Kentico 9: Customizing the Form action based on the page the form is on

Tags: webforms, kentico

I have a form that I want to include on each of 250 pages based on the same pageType.  Thus I want to include the form reference in the template and have it render on all pages. this much seems to be working.
However, I want to have the form to trigger an email send to a different email address based on the pages contactEmail property (entered as a property of the page/ defined on the pageType)

I am guessing I will have to build a custom form control or alternative form, but I don't know where to start and I have been pouring over the documentation for days.
I tried enabling email notification and setting {% CurrentDocument.ContactEmail #%} as the recipient email, but that does not seem to work.

I am not sure what context I can use macros in the form building or if there is a way to reference the current document field values within the form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CurrentDocument` is not available when sending an email, but it is when saving a form. As a workaround I'd suggest you adding a new field to your form e.g. ContactEmail and setting `{% CurrentDocument.ContactEmail #%}` as a default value for it. Now you need to make sure fields is on the page, but hidden with CSS - use a custom layout or an alternative form.

Now when saving form data, the system will save `CurrentDocument.ContactEmail` value along with form.

The last step would be updating `To` field under Email Notification tab of the form with following macro `{% ContactEmail %}`.